# Only one of many Firebase Functions being invoked

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have 2 Firebase functions that I want to execute when there is an Http request, one function (`createEmailList`) to save data in the Firebase database, the other (`zohoCrmHook`) to to save in a 3rd party CRM called Zoho.

When the functions are deployed to Firebase, the functions log shows that both are properly deployed.  However, when the Http request is made from the frontend, the log shows that only one of the functions (`createEmailList`) is being executed.

[image]

As the log shows, the first function `createEmailList` is being executed and the data shows up in the Firebase database with no problem.  However, The second function `zohoCrmHook` is not even being executed.

index.js

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
const serviceAccount = require("./service_account.json");
const createEmailList = require('./createEmailList')

// zoho
const zohoCrmHook = require('./zohoCrmHook')

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://landing-page.firebaseio.com"
})

exports.zohoCrmHook = functions.https.onRequest(zohoCrmHook)
exports.createEmailList = functions.https.onRequest(createEmailList)
```

createEmailList.js

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true })

module.exports = (req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        if (!req.body.email) {
            return res.status(422).send({ error: 'Bad Input'})
        }

        const email = String(req.body.email)
        const firstName = String(req.body.firstName)
        const lastName = String(req.body.lastName)

        const data = {
            email,
            firstName,
            lastName
        }

        const db = admin.firestore()
        const docRef = db.collection('users')
            .doc(email)
            .set(data, { merge: false })
            .catch(err => res.status(422).send({ error: err }))

        res.status(204).end();    
    })
}
```

zohoCrmHook.js

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// zoho
const clientId = functions.config().zoho.client_id;
const clientSecret = functions.config().zoho.client_secret;
const refreshToken = functions.config().zoho.refresh_token;
const baseURL = 'https://accounts.zoho.com';

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
    const newLead = {
        'data': [
        {
            'Email': req.body.email,
            'Last_Name': req.body.lastName,
            'First_Name': req.body.firstName,
        }
        ],
        'trigger': [
            'approval',
            'workflow',
            'blueprint'
        ]
    };

    const { data } = await getAccessToken();
    const accessToken = data.access_token;

    const leads = await getLeads(accessToken);
    const result = checkLeads(leads.data.data, newLead.data[0].Email);

    if (result.length < 1) {
        try {
            return res.json(await createLead(accessToken, newLead));
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
    else res.json({ message: 'Lead already in CRM' })
}

function getAccessToken () {
    const url = `https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token?refresh_token=${refreshToken}&client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&grant_type=refresh_token`;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios.post(url)
        .then((response) => {
          return resolve(response);
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e))
    });
}

function getLeads(token) {
    const url = 'https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Leads';

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios.get(url, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Zoho-oauthtoken ${token}`
        }
      })
        .then((response) => {
          return resolve(response);
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e))
    })
}

function createLead(token, lead) {
    const url = 'https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Leads';

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const data = JSON.stringify(lead);
        axios.post(url, data, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Zoho-oauthtoken ${token}`
        }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data)
            return resolve(response);
        })
        .catch(e => reject(e))
    })
}

function checkLeads(leads, currentLead) {
    return leads.filter(lead => lead.Email === currentLead)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're exporting two `functions.https.onRequest` declarations, you'll end up with two Cloud Functions, each with their own URL/endpoint. So if that's what you need, you'll need to configure two web hooks that call these functions.

---

From reading your question however, it sounds more like you want a single Cloud Function that does two things, in which case you should only have one `functions.https.onRequest` declaration that then calls two regular JavaScript functions (for example).

So something more like:

```
exports.myWebHook = functions.https.onRequest(function(req, res) {
  zohoCrmHook(...);
  createEmailList(...);
})
```

You'll need to figure out what to pass into the two function calls here, as you can't pass the request and response along.

Alternatively you can call the two Cloud Functions from here, but that typically just drives up your cost with little benefit.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What should be inside the parenthesis of `zohoCrmHook(...)` and `createEmail(...)` in your example? Can they be left blank since they are just being imported from another component?

Comment: As said, you'll need to change those functions. You can't simply pass the request and response along, since only one of these functions should be writing to the response (or at least writing headers/closing it).

Comment: If were to call the two endpoints at the same time using `axios.all` with two `axios.post` as an array, is it possible to keep two `functions.https.onRequest` declarations?

Comment: for example, `axios.all([axios.post(...), axios.post(...)]).then(...).catch(...)`.  I've been trying that method with futility, but I just want to know if I'm on the right track.

Comment: Where would this axios call happen? And: why do you want two separate Cloud Functions?